# Compiling React JSX HTML Template on demand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to write in Vanilla JavaScript. I dont want to write things like this:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Hello',
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name);
  }
});
```

I am want to do something like this

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Hello',
  render: reactCompile('mytemplate.html')
});
```

Now, I want to creat mytemplate.html:

```
<div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
```

---

**Now the question:** How to create a function like `reactCompile` that takes a template file, and build a valid JSX function for it?

I'm searching something like in Angular:

```
  directive('',function(){
    return {
       templateUrl:'mytemplate.html'
    }
```

My target is: To keep the debugging & development easy, without compiling without babel, without watching and without node or npm. (The compiler need to run in the browser, not before like in gulp)

Comment: do you want a react-template?

Comment: No. I don't want precompile. I want the compile do work in the browser. If I change file. I just press F5. And please don't suggest me a `watch & compile` :) Thanks

Comment: Checkout this library, which may help you do what you want: https://github.com/mikenikles/html-to-react